# Calling MATLAB or Scilab function from C++ project

Tags: c++, scilab

I'm trying to access some [Scilab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilab) functions from my C++ project. I'm working on Windows 7. How can I do that.?

For example,

```
function  [r] = fun(a,b)
   r =a+b;
endfunction
```

How can I tell my C++ project, it should run the Scilab function "fun" and give the parameter a=4, b=9. so that I get their value?

If somebody did this for [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), I think this will be the same here (without using its engine).

Answer (score 1):

A lead would be to use [Julia](http://julialang.org/) that is quite similar to MATLAB. I'm not sure it's possible yet to compile to a library. The project is based on LLVM so maybe you can generated C code and integrate it with your code.

Comment: looks interesting I'll, if get this with it done. thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

For [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), you can use the [MATLAB compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/), and you should be able find some examples on the MATLAB website.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Scilab runtime aside, but [call_scilab](http://help.scilab.org/docs/current/en_US/call_scilab.html) is probably what you are looking for.